# Does SDWeb image caching the downloaded imaged automatically ?

Tags: ios, image, caching, swift3, sdwebimage

I have a simple collection view which have one image downloaded from URl

and i tried to use SD Web image and it's not caching these images

here's my code

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "carOwnerCell", for: indexPath) as! CarOwnerCollectionViewCell

      cell.requestImage.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
      cell.requestImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "My url "))

      return cell 

    }
```

image downloaded but it's keep downloading the image every time i scroll in the collectionView how can i cache downloading images using SD web image

Comment: You're setting the url on each cell call and it asynchronously check if it exists or not then sets the cached image. You can check by downloading your image once and then turn off internet and scroll up and down.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check ("my url")is this correct URL for image and then give placeholder image ,if it displays placeholder image means works fine